# Do we use probabilities to show electron position because of how fast it's going?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces

A hydrogen's electron shell has a radius of $.53 \ Å$. The velocity of the electron is $2.182 \times 10^{8}$. That's $6.55 \times 10^{15}$ revolutions per second. Do we use probabilities to show electron position because of how fast it's going? That's a lot of rotations and some aren't going to be perfect, so does that cause the behavior of electrons?

Answer (score 4):

No.

We use probabilities because on the microscopic scale, an electron is not what we classically imagine a particle to be. It doesn't have one fixed location, never. When we write down a probability distribution, those are really probabilities for where the electron *is* - the uncertainty is part of reality, not of how well we can measure it.

Note that the electron also doesn't have a fixed velocity, and on average the velocity of the electron is $\langle \vec v \rangle = 0$ for symmetry reasons, i.e. because it can go in each direction with the same probability (assuming $s$-orbital). When someone estimates the average velocity, it will be something more complicated like $\sqrt{\langle \vec v^2 \rangle}$. Such estimates show that the electron does indeed have an average kinetic energy on the order of magnitude you're thinking of (I guess, you are missing a unit in your question).

But don't imagine the electron as going in revolutions around the core.
The "shell radius" you're quoting is also some made-up quantity, in your case it comes from the (long) outdated Bohr model.
There are just places where the electron is more likely, and places where it is less likely to be.
In fact, the electron is most likely in the "center of the shell" and less likely further outside.